# How to login on website with PHP Curl library?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, authentication, csrf

I want to login to a page on https using the PHP CURL library. Reload this Page. But I couldn't. I could not make the connection from the server or localhost.

```
 $username = "pik123@gmail.com";
$password = "Bf*****";
$url = "https://eksisozluk.com/giris";
$cookie= "cookies.txt";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($response);
$tokens = $dom->getElementsByTagName("meta");
for ($i = 0; $i < $tokens->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $tokens->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'csrf-token')
    $token = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}
$postinfo = "UserName=".$username."&Password=".$password."&_csrf=".$token;
echo $token; //debug info
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
    print($html);
if (curl_errno($ch)) print curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I'm printing a cookie. Just giving you a blank sheet. I'm getting the error message.

Comment: almost all websites have their own custom login system, specific to their own website and not applicable anywhere else, including these guys

Comment: also.. this website uses both cookies and a CSRF token, your code fetches neither the CSRF token nor the cookie required to log in

Comment: .. after the for() loop, add `if(empty($token)){die("error: unable to extract CSRF token!");}`  , then what do you get? (i already know the answer, but you should have realized it yourself)

Comment: .. also you forgot to urlencode `$username` and `$password` and `$token`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try to send the login credentials before getting a cookie, but the website requires you to already have a cookie PRIOR to logging in. also, the website use a [CSRF token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Synchronizer_token_pattern) which you need to fetch prior to logging in, but you don't. also, your username and password needs to be urlencoded, but you don't urlencode it, for example the @ is wrong, it should have been `Username=pik123%40gmail.com` (`@` urlencoded is `%40` ), also the username variable is called `UserName`, not `Username`,

first fetch the login page with a normal GET request, this will get you both the cookie you need, and the CSRF token,

then parse out the CSRF token, and send a POST request to the login page with the cookie and the CSRF token in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, with `__RequestVerificationToken` as the CSRF token and `UserName` as the username (and be more careful with the CaPiTaLiZaTiOn here, it's `UserName`, not `Username`), and `Password` as the password, and a seemingly hardcoded parameter called `ReturnUrl` which just contains `/` (urlencoded ofc, which is `%2F`, eg `ReturnUrl=%2F`), and you should get logged in (your cookie session will now be logged in), provided you have valid credentials.

example with the [hhb_curl library](https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php) (which takes care of cookie handling and curl error checking, converting curl errors to RuntimeExceptions):

```
<?php
declare (strict_types = 1);
require_once('hhb_.inc.php');
$username = "pik123@gmail.com";
$password = "Bf*****";
$hc = new hhb_curl('', true);
// get cookie and csrc token:
$html = $hc->exec('https://eksisozluk.com/giris')->getStdOut();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);
// grab the login form (it contains the csrf token, among other things)
$login_form = $xp->query("//form[contains(@action,'/giris')]")->item(0);
$login_parameters = array();
foreach ($login_form->getElementsByTagName("input") as $input) {
    $login_parameters[$input->getAttribute("name")] = $input->getAttribute("value");
}
// the CSRF token is called `__RequestVerificationToken`, and $login_parameters now contains roughly:
// array(
//  '__RequestVerificationToken' => 'qTk2Ik0glfV8W1WckmrVkVXujQE8C1eTqMEe36SP-PPUXDn88GG0XYxif3ZMIVGZH08-MEbbtD7i7Q4ymxuasveDZL-WaHQH22r33fOdsqQ1',
//  'ReturnUrl' => '/',
//  'UserName' => '',
//  'Password' => '',
//  'RememberMe' => 'false',
// );
assert(isset($login_parameters['UserName']));
assert(isset($login_parameters['Password']));
$login_parameters['UserName'] = $username;
$login_parameters['Password'] = $password;
// log in
$html = $hc->setopt_array(array(
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($login_parameters)
))->exec()->getStdOut();
// check for login errors:
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);
$login_errors = array();
foreach ($xp->query("//*[contains(@class,'validation-error')]") as $login_error) {
    $login_error = trim($login_error->textContent);
    if (!empty($login_error)) {
        $login_errors[] = $login_error;
    }
}
unset($login_error);
if (!empty($login_errors)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException("eksisozluk login errors: " . print_r($login_errors, true));
}
```

output:

```
$ php wtf4.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: eksisozluk login errors: Array
(
    [0] => captcha'yı yanlış girdiniz.
)
 in /cygdrive/c/projects/misc/wtf4.php:46
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /cygdrive/c/projects/misc/wtf4.php on line 46
```

- because `pik123@gmail.com` / `Bf*****`  is not valid login credentials.

Comment: Sorry. I did what you said, but unfortunately not. I also edited my question.

Comment: @PikettyThoma .. after the for() loop, add `if(empty($token)){die("error: unable to extract CSRF token!");}` , then what do you get? (i already know the answer, but you should have realized it yourself)

Comment: mail address "% 40gmail.com" I did.
After the FOR cycle
cookies.txt did not occur when I added "if (empty ($ token)) {die (" error: unable to extract CSRF token! ");}". and "error: unable to extract CSRF token!" got the error. where am I making mistakes.

Comment: @PikettyThoma you're fetching the CSRF token wrong, and you're not urlencoding the token, nor the username, nor the password. for example, `$postinfo` should look something like `$postinfo = "UserName=".urlencode($username)."&Password=".urlencode($password)."&__RequestVerificationToken=".urlencode($token);`  (or better yet, use http_build_query() to build the string for you from a php-array)

Comment: Although the username and password are correct, I get the error you received.

Comment: @PikettyThoma hmm, seems that after too many failed login attempts, your IP address will be put on a captcha-list where you need to fill in a captcha before logging in.. try logging in from a fresh IP, do you still get the error?

Comment: I changed the ip address. now the username or password gave incorrect warning. I'm sure they're right. I can connect from the website's own page.

Comment: I changed the username to "string". I did not use special characters in the password. I added "echo $ html;" at the end of the code. and bingoooo, it worked.

Comment: @PikettyThoma that just means, again, you didn't properly urlencode your POST parameters, but whatever. you should read up on  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php